# How to add a Form submit button just after fields in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

How can I add a button just after adding all form fields? I know I can add buttons with `buttons` config of `Ext.form.Panel`. But it adds buttons at the docked bar. For me this docked bar is located at the lowest part of the screen. So I want to add it Just after the items. This is the config object I pass to `items` config option of `Ext.form.Panel`.

```
        items: [
           // other fields here
        , {
            xtype: 'panel',
            frame: true,
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                pack: 'end'
            },
            items:[{
                text: 'Change',
                xtype: 'button'
            }]
         }
```

Output is 
[image]

But I want the button to be **aligned with above text fields**.

How can I do that?

I am using ExtJS 4.0.7. I can not update this version as the project is large and very complex.

Answer (score 1):

Ext.form.Panel have a buttonAlign property: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-cfg-buttonAlign
You can just add a xtype: 'button' in FormPanel items and configure it: http://jsfiddle.net/Un5rW/

If you want add a button inside a another panel, then not set a "pack" property of panel layout to end:

```
...
layout: {
    type: 'hbox'//,
    //pack: 'end' <----
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Un5rW/1/

**UPD**

One more example with end of form fields button aligment: http://jsfiddle.net/Un5rW/2/

Comment: Your first two fiddles put button left aligned which is default with `anchor` layout. This is not what I want. I want something like last fiddle. But its dirty hack. Do you know any other way?